# How to make a button appear pressed in libGDX?

Tags: image, button, libgdx, scene2d

So I have an ImageButton that has a texture for when it's not clicked and another one for when it is.

I'd like to make it so that under certain circumstances it becomes disabled also appear as if it's clicked (displaying its "clicked" texture).

So far `button.setDisabled(true)` has worked wonders but it doesn't make the button appear clicked. I searched through the whole Scene2d ImageButton doc and couldn't find a single method that could do that for me. Any ideas how can I achieve it?

Comment: did you try http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.html#setChecked-boolean- ?

Comment: @MoshErsan Yes, and it did not work. On its own at least..

Answer (score 0):

Try using ImageButtonStyle to set the drawables for the various states of the button. It also includes a drawable for the disabled state, which you can set to be the same drawable that you used for the checked state.
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle.html

Comment: I tried `Button.ButtonStyle style = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle(buttonUp, buttonDown, buttonDown, buttonUp, buttonDown, buttonDown);` but my button would behave very oddly. I also tried `style.disabled = buttonDown;` on a default style constructor but my button simply disappeared. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle style = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle() and then setting just the states you need. Start with style.imageUp = buttonUp; and style.imageChecked = buttonDown; and test to make sure the button is working normally. Then try adding style.imageDisabled = buttonDown; Also, are "buttonUp" and "buttonDown" both Drawables? ImageButtonStyle only works with Drawables.